# Reverse inside 2D forloop svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I Have a 2D array of cells and Im trying to make a div for each cell, I have the following svelte code
that doesn't work.

```js
{#each [...cells].reverse() as row}
    {#each [...row].reverse() as cell}
        <div bind:this={cell.div}>
    {/each}
{/each}
```

When im running that code the site just freeze and dont load anything at all

Comment: Can you make a minimal REPL?

Answer (score 0):

When you spread the array you are effectively creating a new array, with references to the same objects.
You then loop over each of these objects modifying them.
Svelte's reactivity sees the object has changed.
This in turn triggers a new spreading, which is *again* a new object
Because of this the `{#each}` block is rerun, destroying the old divs and creating new ones.
These new ones are then registered to the objects again.
Triggering a change and therefore...

You are effectively creating an infinite loop.

The simplest form of this form would be:

```svelte
<script>
  const arr = [{ value: 1 }]
  $: console.log(arr[0].div)
</script>
{#each [...arr] as item}
  <div bind:this={item.div}>{item.value}</div>
{/each}
```

Which brings me to the question: why are spreading the array instead of just reversing it ?

Comment: I tried it without spreading and it didnt work, and I read somewhere online that spreading might fix it. I found the problem was with "bind:this", and I fixed it by assigning the value from the array itself "bind:this={cells[i][j].div}"